# How to deal with Number precision in Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have BigDecimal objects serialized with BlazeDS to Actionscript. Once they hit Actionscript as Number objects, they have values like:

`140475.32` turns into `140475.31999999999998`

How do I deal with this? The problem is that if I use a [NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html) with precision of 2, then the value is truncated to `140475.31`. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI in AS 3 it looks like they actually added the 'toPrecision' method. 

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html#toPrecision()

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this, the accepted answer is NOT correct in all situations. A simple example is .575. If you do Math.round(.575 * 100)/100 you get .57.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is my generic solution for the problem *(I have [blogged about this here](http://fraserchapman.blogspot.com/2007/05/rounding-to-specific-decimal-places.html))*:

```
var toFixed:Function = function(number:Number, factor:int) {
  return Math.round(number * factor)/factor;
}
```

*For example:*

```
trace(toFixed(0.12345678, 10)); //0.1
```

- Multiply `0.12345678` by `10`; that gives us `1.2345678`.
- When we round `1.2345678`, we get `1.0`,
- and finally, `1.0` divided by `10` equals `0.1`.

*Another example:*

```
trace(toFixed(1.7302394309234435, 10000)); //1.7302
```

- Multiply `1.7302394309234435` by `10000`; that gives us `17302.394309234435`.
- When we round `17302.394309234435` we get `17302`,
- and finally, `17302` divided by `10000` equals `1.7302`.

---

**Edit**

Based on the anonymous answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541929/74861),  there is a nice simplification for the parameter on the method that makes the precision much more intuitive. *e.g:*

```
var setPrecision:Function = function(number:Number, precision:int) {
 precision = Math.pow(10, precision);
 return Math.round(number * precision)/precision;
}

var number:Number = 10.98813311;
trace(setPrecision(number,1)); //Result is 10.9
trace(setPrecision(number,2)); //Result is 10.98
trace(setPrecision(number,3)); //Result is 10.988 and so on
```

N.B. I added this here just in case anyone sees this as the answer and doesn't scroll down...

Comment: Why is that "*=" and not "*"?

Comment: How is this different from the native toFixed function?

Comment: @ grapefrukt - toFixed just gives the same problem in the original question! in that is just gives you the right number of digits with out the correct rounding. Actually toPrecision looks like it but I was unaware that this had been included in AS, I haven't touched it since 2.0!

Comment: @jder - stylistic. x *= y  is x = x * y

Comment: I would change it to number * factor - the assignment is causing no purpose and is setting a local register for no reason.

Comment: toPrecision actually returns a string, which means you have to reparse it. Nice one, Adobe!

Comment: Math.round(number * factor)/factor;
<--- This method is flawed in AS3 as it has rounding error problems. Put it under test and you'll see this: expected:<2826.1> but was:<2826.1000000000004>  The 2nd method is better.

Comment: toPrecision must include trailing zeros which is why it returns a string.

Comment: How can we be sure that any division by power of 10 will give us exactly needed number of cyphers within fraction part? Computation is done using binary interpretation, not decimal (since Intel's software library not used or any hardware technique).

Comment: @Brian - I have, I wrote it and have used it and it works well in AS2 - I'm guessing you aren't using AS2 - so perhaps you should be using toPrecision in any case?

Answer (score 20):

Just a slight variation on [Frasers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632914/3709765) Function, for anyone who is interested.

```
function setPrecision(number:Number, precision:int) {
 precision = Math.pow(10, precision);
 return (Math.round(number * precision)/precision);
}
```

So to use:

```
var number:Number = 10.98813311;
trace(setPrecision(number,1)); //Result is 10.9
trace(setPrecision(number,2)); //Result is 10.98
trace(setPrecision(number,3)); //Result is 10.988 and so on
```

Answer (score 10):

i've used `Number.toFixed(precision)` in ActionScript 3 to do this:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Number.html#toFixed%28%29

it handles rounding properly and specifies the number of digits after the decimal to display - unlike `Number.toPrecision()` that limits the total number of digits to display regardless of the position of the decimal.

```
var roundDown:Number = 1.434;                                             
// will print 1.43                                                        
trace(roundDown.toFixed(2));                                              

var roundUp:Number = 1.436;                                               
// will print 1.44                                                        
trace(roundUp.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Only sad thing is that it's not localized. You have to use a NumberFormatter if your language uses a comma as the decimal point separator.

Comment: Moreover, it's a String, not a Number. Sometimes this is desirable (like in your trace statements) but not always, in fact, not most of the time. Plus it's slow to convert back using `parseInt()`

Comment: toFixed also doesn't work in all situations. If you replace roundUp with .575 it yields .57 (.255 yields .26; this particular number does weird floating point things), so it seems to suffer from the same issues as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

I converted the Java of BigDecimal to ActionScript.
We had no choices since we compute for financial application.

http://code.google.com/p/bigdecimal/

Answer (score 1):

You can use property: rounding = "nearest"

In NumberFormatter, rounding have 4 values which you can choice: rounding="none|up|down|nearest". I think with your situation, you can chose rounding = "nearest".

-- chary --

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that BlazeDS supports serializing Java BigDecimal objects to ActionScript Strings as well. So if you don't need the ActionScript data to be Numbers (you are not doing any math on the Flex / ActionScript side) then the String mapping works well (no rounding weirdness). See this link for the BlazeDS mapping options: http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_2.html

Answer (score 1):

GraniteDS 2.2 has BigDecimal, BigInteger and Long implementations in ActionScript3, serialization options between Java / Flex for these types, and even code generation tools options in order to generate AS3 big numbers variables for the corresponding Java ones.

See more here: http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC22/2.+Big+Number+Implementations.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to reuse one of the available BigDecimal.as classes on the web and extended blazeds by sublassing from AMF3Output, you'll need to specify your own endpoint class in the flex xml files, in that custom endpoint you can insert your own serializer that instantiates an AMF3Output subclass.

```
public class EnhancedAMF3Output extends Amf3Output {

    public EnhancedAMF3Output(final SerializationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void writeObject(final Object o) throws IOException {           
        if (o instanceof BigDecimal) {
            write(kObjectType);
            writeUInt29(7); // write U290-traits-ext (first 3 bits set)
            writeStringWithoutType("java.math.BigDecimal");
            writeAMFString(((BigDecimal)o).toString());
        } else {
            super.writeObject(o);
        }
    }
}
```

as simple as that! then you have native BigDecimal support using blazeds, wooohoo!
Make sure your BigDecimal as3 class implements IExternalizable

cheers, jb

Answer (score 1):

guys, just check the solution:

```
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var formatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
                formatter.precision = 2;
                formatter.rounding = NumberBaseRoundType.NEAREST;
                var a:Number = 14.31999999999998;

                trace(formatter.format(a)); //14.32
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ported the IBM ICU implementation of BigDecimal for the Actionscript client.  [Someone else has published their nearly identical version here as a google code project.](http://code.google.com/p/bigdecimal/)  Our version adds some convenience methods for doing comparisons.

You can extend the Blaze AMF endpoint to add serialization support for BigDecimal.  Please note that the code in the other answer seems incomplete, and in our experience it fails to work in production.

AMF3 assumes that duplicate objects, traits and strings are sent by reference.  The object reference tables need to be kept in sync while serializing, or the client will loose sync of these tables during deserialization and start throwing class cast errors, or corrupting the data in fields that don't match, but cast ok...

Here is the corrected code:

```
public void writeObject(final Object o) throws IOException {
    if (o instanceof BigDecimal) {
        write(kObjectType);
        if(!byReference(o)){   // if not previously sent
            String s = ((BigDecimal)o).toString();                  
            TraitsInfo ti = new TraitsInfo("java.math.BigDecimal",false,true,0);
            writeObjectTraits(ti); // will send traits by reference
            writeUTF(s);
            writeObjectEnd();  // for your AmfTrace to be correctly indented
        }
    } else {
            super.writeObject(o);
        }
}
```

There is another way to send a typed object, which does not require Externalizable on the client.  The client will set the **textValue** property on the object instead:

```
TraitsInfo ti = new TraitsInfo("java.math.BigDecimal",false,false,1);           
ti.addProperty("textValue");
writeObjectTraits(ti);
writeObjectProperty("textValue",s);
```

In either case, your Actionscript class will need this tag:

```
[RemoteClass(alias="java.math.BigDecimal")]
```

The Actionscript class also needs a text property to match the one you chose to send that will initialize the BigDecimal value, or in the case of the Externalizable object, a couple of methods like this:

```
public  function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void {       
    output.writeUTF(this.toString());
}
public  function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {          
    var s:String = input.readUTF();
    setValueFromString(s);
}
```

This code only concerns data going from server to client.  To deserialize in the other direction from client to server, we chose to extend AbstractProxy, and use a wrapper class to temporarily store the string value of the BigDecimal before the actual object is created, due to the fact that you cannot instantiate a BigDecimal and then assign the value, as the design of Blaze/LCDS expects should be the case with all objects.

Here's the proxy object to circumvent the default handling:

```
public class BigNumberProxy extends AbstractProxy {

    public BigNumberProxy() {
        this(null);
    }

    public BigNumberProxy(Object defaultInstance) {
        super(defaultInstance);
        this.setExternalizable(true);

        if (defaultInstance != null)
           alias = getClassName(defaultInstance);
    }   

    protected String getClassName(Object instance) {
        return((BigNumberWrapper)instance).getClassName();
    }

    public Object createInstance(String className) {
        BigNumberWrapper w = new BigNumberWrapper();
        w.setClassName(className);
        return w;
    }

    public Object instanceComplete(Object instance) {
    String desiredClassName = ((BigNumberWrapper)instance).getClassName();
    if(desiredClassName.equals("java.math.BigDecimal"))
        return new BigDecimal(((BigNumberWrapper)instance).stringValue);
    return null;
}

    public String getAlias(Object instance) {
        return((BigNumberWrapper)instance).getClassName();
    }

}
```

This statement will have to execute somewhere in your application, to tie the proxy object to the class you want to control.  We use a static method:

```
PropertyProxyRegistry.getRegistry().register(
    java.math.BigDecimal.class, new BigNumberProxy());
```

Our wrapper class looks like this:

```
public class BigNumberWrapper implements Externalizable {

    String stringValue;
    String className;

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput arg0) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stringValue = arg0.readUTF();       
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        arg0.writeUTF(stringValue);     
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a complete sample that demostrates how it is set up?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly the round function in MS Excel gives us different values then you have presented above.
For example in Excel

`Round(143,355;2)` = `143,36`

So my workaround for Excel round is like:

```
public function setPrecision(number:Number, precision:int):Number {
precision = Math.pow(10, precision);

const excelFactor : Number = 0.00000001;

number += excelFactor;

return (Math.round(number * precision)/precision);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the precision you need beforehand, you could store the numbers scaled so that the smallest amount you need is a whole value. For example, store the numbers as cents rather than dollars.

If that's not an option, how about something like this:

```
function printTwoDecimals(x)
{
   printWithNoDecimals(x);
   print(".");
   var scaled = Math.round(x * 100);
   printWithNoDecimals(scaled % 100);
}
```

(With however you print with no decimals stuck in there.)

This won't work for *really* big numbers, though, because you can still lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

You may vote and watch the enhancement request in the Flash PLayer Jira bug tracking system at https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-3315

And meanwhile use the Number.toFixed() work-around see :
(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Number.html#toFixed%28%29)

or use the open source implementations out there : (http://code.google.com/p/bigdecimal/) or (http://www.fxcomps.com/money.html)

As for the serialization efforts, well, it will be small if you use Blazeds or LCDS as they do support  Java BigDecimal serialization (to String) cf. (http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/lcds/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=serialize_data_3.html)

Answer (score -1):

It seems more like a transport problem, the number being correct but the scale ignored. If the number has to be stored as a BigDecimal on the server you may want to convert it server side to a less ambiguous format (Number, Double, Float) before sending it.

Comment: Java BigDecimal can be converted to AS3 String. BigDecimal is necessary for extremely large numbers: Number doesn't exist in Java; while double and float types are not big enough.