# how to get numbers to have precision of .05?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript, floating-point, rounding

The following will ensure that any large numbers will only be precise to the hundredths place ([related to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632802/how-to-deal-with-number-precision-in-actionscript)):

```
public function round( sc:Number ):Number
{
    sc = sc * 100;
    sc = Math.floor( sc );
    sc = sc / 100;

    return sc;
}
```

What is the optimal way to round my numbers to the precision of .05?  Is there something clever to be done with bit-shifting to get this result?  For example, I would like:

3.4566 = 3.45

3.04232   = 3.05

3.09   = 3.1

3.32   = 3.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could multiply by 20, round, then divide by 20.

Edit: You will want to use Math.round() instead of Math.floor(), otherwise your test case 3.09 will turn into 3.05.

Answer (score 2):

You could just change the *100 to *20 and /100 /20. But why stop there, when you can naturally generalize?

```
double floor(double in, double precision) {
    return Math.floor(in/precision)*precision
}
//floor(1.07, 0.05) = 1.05
```

Comment: This should be Math.round(), not Math.floor().

Comment: His example used floor, so I used floor. Also notice I called the function floor to make it clear.

Comment: To get consistent results for negative numbers you should also add 0.5 to the "in / precision" result passed to Math.floor()

Comment: That would make it a rounding function, not a floor function. Floor rounds towards negative infinity. What you're thinking of is called truncation.