# BlazeDS marshalls Java Float to ActionScript int

Tags: flash, apache-flex, serialization, actionscript, blazeds

I'm using BlazeDS to marshall Java objects to Flex. What I'm seeing is that if a Java `Float` holds a integer value (whole number, such as 123), then it gets marshalled to a ActionScript `int`. I would expect that a Java `Float` always gets marshalled to an ActionScript `Number` as [documented in the BlazeDS Developer Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html).

Is there a way to configure this or is this just a BlazeDS bug?

**Follow-up**: The float is contained within a map. The Java map that is being passed to BlazeDS looks something like:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Float f = 123.0;
map.put("number", f);
```

When it arrives on the Flex side `map` is an `Object`:

```
var map:Object = ...
trace(map.number);
trace(getQualifiedClassName(map.number));
```

prints:

```
123
int
```

So it's serializing the value correctly, just as the wrong type.

Comment: Can you show the code on how you're doing it on the Flex end?  Are you using RemoteAlias or just dynamic objects?

Comment: I believe by default that if you don't specify a value object on the Flex end, it will try to use the lowest possible value (int in this case) as your type.

Comment: What is the Flex type if the Java value is 1.23?

Comment: Java 1.23 --> ActionScript 1.23 of type `Number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with BlazeDS itself. It's a AS3 "feature"..

This will help understanding what's going on. Or confuse you even more...

First thing: *****JAVA: java.lang.Float and float ==> AS3: Number *****

```
var number:Number = 4.5;
trace(typeof(number) == "number");      //true
trace(number is Number);                //true

var integer:int = 2;
trace(typeof(integer) == "number");     //true!
trace(integer is Number);               //true!

//number=4.5
trace(number is int);                   //false
trace(getQualifiedClassName(number));   //Number

//Here comes the fun..
number=number-0.5; //number=4
trace(number is int);                   //true!!
trace(getQualifiedClassName(number));   //int!!
```

Hope this actually helped!

Comment: Yes, it is not BlazeDS related.

Answer (score 0):

Are the variable names same in AS3/Java value objects?

In the value object , that has RemoteClass tag,
AS3

```
public var myfloat:Number;
```

Java

```
public float myfloat = 10.4f;
```

For precision info: Look at this post:
[How to deal with Number precision in Actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632802/how-to-deal-with-number-precision-in-actionscript)