# Actionscript 3.0 number type multiplication error..

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to multiply to number type variables: The code is something like this::

```
trace(6.60*6);// !=39.6
var a:Number=6.6;
var b:Number=6;
trace(a*b);// !=39.6
```

it is not equal to 39.6 in Action Script 3.0 .. instead showing 39.5999999994...

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, I can't think of any language language where `a*b == 39.6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a by product of IEEE standard of floating point arithmetic.  If you want the real reason why check this paper:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Most of this comes from Actionscript's Javascript roots, and in Javascript everything is floating point.  There is no diference between ints and floating point math so strange errors crop up that don't crop up in other languages, but they would if you alway used floats.

Answer (score 0):

I've never head of a completely "clean feeling" way of rounding to precision in Actionscript, the next best things can be found here:

[How to deal with Number precision in Actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632802/how-to-deal-with-number-precision-in-actionscript)