# as3 Number precision

Tags: actionscript-3, precision

I am trying to round some numbers in two decimal point and I run into a bizare behavior.

please try the following code:

```
var num:Number  = 30.25
for (var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    var a:Number  = (Math.round(num * 100) / 100)
    var b:Number  =  (Math.round(num * 100) * 0.01 )
    trace (num.toString() + " -- " + a.toString() + " -- " + b.toString())
    num += 0.999;
}
```

x = y /100 and x = y * 0.01 should be equal.

(And x = y * 0.01 should be faster).

But if I run the above code the result is not always equal.

I get for example

- 46.23400000000003 -- 46.23 -- 46.230000000000004
  47.23300000000003 -- 47.23 -- 47.230000000000004
  48.232000000000035 -- 48.23 -- 48.230000000000004
  49.23100000000004 -- 49.23 -- 49.230000000000004

while x=y/100 is always correct x=y*0.01 sometimes adds a small value like 0.000000000000004 at the end.

Am I doing something wrong?
Has anyone else observed this behavior?

Comment: thats just how it is... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632802/how-to-deal-with-number-precision-in-actionscript

Answer (score 2):

**In general, in floating point computations you should try to avoid numbers of really different magnitude in the same calculation.** That's precisely the issue with these types: the point "floats", so you want to keep the point of one number of the computation close to the point of the other number.

Your question is simply put as

> Why is 4623/100 == 46.23 but 4623*0.01 == 46.230000000000004?

For the specific reason, you can dig in the specific of floating point computation, for example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-math2/index.html).

4623 is 4.623*10^3 while 0.01 is 1*10^{-3}, notice how the exponent is really different (6 orders of magnitude of difference). While 100 is just 1*10^{2}, much "closer" to 4.623*10^3.